# What are the elements of $(\mathbb{Q}_{2}/(\mathbb{Q}_{2})^{2})^{\times}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

The answer is $\{-1, \pm 2,\pm 5, \pm 10\}$ and I can't even figure out why 10 is there.
I mean the 2-adic unit rationals. It turns out that $\mathbb{Q}_{2}^{\times}/(\mathbb{Q}_{2}^{\times})^{2}\simeq (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{3}$. Let's start with the elements of $(\mathbb{Q}_{2})^{\times}$.  What are they? Is $\pm 10$ one of them?

Comment: What do you call $\;\left(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\right)^3\;$ to? Because this is a usual notation of the direct product of $\;\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\;$ with itself thrice, either as a group, as a ring (field),etc. But then representatives of what with respect to what? Of perhaps you mean the group of all cubed elements of the group? But then how is $\;5=1=1^3\pmod 2\;$ not a cubic residue modulo $\;2\;$ ??

Comment: I changed the question.

Comment: Then what you call "the answer" makes no sense, as an element in the set (group) you define is a $\;3$-ary element $\;(a,b,c)\;,\;\;a,b,c\in\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\;$ ...The "answer" you give seems to point towards to possibility this question is part from another one, and you're probably working with integers modulo something, but I can't, and I don't want, to guess. Also, note your "answer" contains only 7 elements, and the cartesian product has to have $\;8\;$ elements...

Comment: @Don The answer is correct, and isomorphic to $(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)^3$, but all of the context is missing for readers to infer this (lost in the edit history).

Comment: It can **not** be correct as the number of element in "the answer" is incorrect, @seaturtles ... and the context is **all** what matters here, of course. In this case, I call it "given data".

Comment: The OP put $-$ instead of $\pm$ before the $1$, a trivial error. That issue is small beans compared to editing out the context, which is a fatal mistake.

Comment: You seem to know what the OP meant in a rather ill-posed question. I don't, so I'd rather wait until the OP addresses these concerns.

Comment: I changed the question again.

Comment: And now the question shifted *completely* to the "$\;2$-adic rationals"[sic], and the units group...

Comment: Yeah, @TKM...I think I'll pass. Good luck.

Comment: Well, it is actually the same question. I just added the context.

Comment: @DonAntonio That's actually what it was originally (see the edit history), so we're only just now seeing the *second* shift :)

Comment: @DonAntonio Couldn't the OP mean modding out by the subgroup of all squares?  Then the question would be about $\mathbb{Q}_2^\times/(\mathbb{Q}_2^\times)^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every nonzero element of $\Bbb Q_p$ may be written as $p^nu$ for some $n\in\Bbb Z$ and $u\in\Bbb Z_p^\times$. Use this fact to prove that $\Bbb Q_p^\times\cong \Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z_p^\times$. Can you tell what the isomorphism is? Note this holds for any $p$.

The subgroup of squares corresponds to $2\Bbb Z\times(\Bbb Z_p^\times)^2$. (How?) You can use Hensel's lemma to prove that $(\Bbb Z_2^\times)^2$ is precisely $1+2^3\Bbb Z_2$ (note this works out differently for odd primes). This is precisely the kernel of the map $\Bbb Z_2^\times\to (\Bbb Z/2^3\Bbb Z)^\times$ (the mod $8$ map), so to get a system of representatives we merely need to pick representatives for elements in $(\Bbb Z/2^3\Bbb Z)^\times$, the most obvious is $\{1,3,5,7\}$ but this can also be written $\{\pm1,\pm5\}$. For the $\Bbb Z$ component of $\Bbb Q_2^\times$, the powers of $2$, the system of representatives are $0$ and $1$ which correspond to $2^0$ and $2^1$ multiplicatively in $\Bbb Q^\times_2$. Therefore,

$$\frac{\Bbb Q_2^\times}{(\Bbb Q_2^\times)^2}\cong\frac{\Bbb Z}{2\Bbb Z}\times\left(\frac{\Bbb Z}{2^3\Bbb Z}\right)^\times\cong\left(\frac{\Bbb Z}{2\Bbb Z}\right)^3$$

with a system of representatives given by $\{2^0,2^1\}\cdot\{\pm1,\pm5\}=\{\pm1,\pm2,\pm5,\pm10\}$.